# Does react-dom/server work on the client-side?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, client-side, server-side, react-dom

I need to render top-level html tags on the client-side (for example, `<html><head>...</head><body></body></html>`). The result will be injected into an iframe. On the server, I would use the `renderToStaticMarkup` function from `react-dom/server`, but the client-only `react-dom` doesn't have this function.

Will `react-dom/server` work on the client in the latest version of react (currently 15.3.0)? If so, is there any indication from the react dev team that it will continue to be supported on the client in future versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: yes.

I verified that it works in `react@15.3.0`. The facebook/react team actually left it as part of react itself but only exposed it as `React.__SECRET_DOM_SERVER_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED`. If you want, you could use it like that directly:

```
var ReactDOMServer = React.__SECRET_DOM_SERVER_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED;
console.log(ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<div />)); // => <div></div>
```

Of course, you'll probably get fired if you do that...

Luckily, they also created a client-side version of react-dom/server (`react-dom-server-15.3.0.min.js`). There's not much to that script. All it does is expose `React.__SECRET_DOM_SERVER_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED` as ReactDOMServer (using a UMD wrapper).

I can only assume that if the react team went through the effort to create a browser build for it, it is intended to continue working on the client-side and will continue to be supported in the future.

Comment: FYI: not supported in React 16+
seems like they've narrowed this API to `__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED`, which is core essentials of internal reactDOM logic

I will note that ReactDomServer is supported by both client & server, but their UMD build doesn't include ReactDOMServer OOTB